# PHP Image gallery that integrates well into custom CMS

Tags: looking-for-a-script, photo-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I've been trying to find an image gallery that plays nice with our custom CMS. I've evaluated a number of them, but none of them seems to have the feature list that I would like:

- Run on LAMP environment
- Free software or low license costs (the website belongs to a non-profit organisation)
- Multi-user support
- Multiple albums. We're posting concert pictures, and would like an album per event.
- Pluggable authentication system. I want to reuse the accounts we have for our CMS. Permissions can be done inside the gallery itself, but I want to have a single sign on solution in a maintainable manner, by writing my own plugin/add-on for the software.
- Upload support (multiple images at the same time)

And preferrably also:

- Can be integrated into a PHP page layout without IFRAMEs
- Automatic resizing of uploaded images to a maximum size
- Ability for visitors to place comments

This combination is proving hard to find, especially the authentication requirement. I don't want to mess around all over the place in the source code to make it use the existing authentication. A plugin would be ideal, but alternatively a well thought out software design that allows for maintainable surgical changes would be acceptable.

Any suggestions on which software I should take a closer look into?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Coppermine Photo Gallery](http://coppermine-gallery.net/): it seems to have all the features you need.